# compiling a list using select elements from an external file in python

Tags: python, list

okay, so I have 2 external files (GirlNames.txt and BoyNames.txt). Each file is a list of an entry number and a name.

example:

```
1.  Michael
2.  Ken
3.  Rebecca
```

About 300 names in total between the two files. I want to take the files, process them so that at the end of the process I have a single list of just names like so:

```
names = ['Michael','Ken','Rebecca']
```

I can see that in order to do this I need to open each file, read each line, and then pass that line to a list. using .split(.) will give me a series of lists formatted with the entry number at [0] and the name at [1]. Okay, so then I can just remove the first index value, and add the value to the final list.

So this is what I have come up with so far (just working with one file for the moment):

```
file_xy = open("BoyNames.txt", "r")
for aline in file_xy:
    value = aline.split('.')
    entry = value.pop(0)
    file_xy.append(entry)
print(file_xy)
```

Now quickie clarification because I'm not totally sure pop() is the right method for this. The explanations I found for it were somewhat contradictory. Does pop() remove the value from the index but leave the index effectively blank, or does it remove the index? I've found explanations that suggest either. If it doesn't remove the index, what method does? I tried every variant of del I could think of and every one threw up an invalid syntex error.

The particular error I can recieving at this point is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "Names-7.py", line 20, in <module>
file_xy.append(entry)
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'append'
```

did I pass entry incorrectly? If so, how do I need to pass it?

Comment: `file_xy` is a file object, not a list.  It has no `append()` method.  If you want to write to a file, use `write()`.

Comment: Also, `pop()` does remove the value from the sequence.  But your loop immediately throws away the sequence, so it doesn't much matter here.

Comment: Try `number, name = aline.split('.')` instead of popping.

Comment: Please do not continually refine the question based on responses.  If someone answers the question, accept it and post a different question for a different problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are treating `file_xy` like a list, which it isn't. Instead you should declare a new list and append to it like so:

```
out_list = []
for aline in file_xy:
    value = aline.split('.')
    entry = value[0] #no reason to use pop here since value isn't used afterwards
    out_list.append(entry)
print(out_list)
```